# how to create a rect under new ui canvas?

Tags: user-interface, canvas, unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

I wanna ask how to create a rect and put it under the canvas of unity new ui? So this is what i made.
[image: my controller view]

you can see my game controller. i put that controller on a canvas. When my "Character" goes to NPC, and going to have a dialogue, i made a dialogue box using Rect from my code. and this is what i got.

[image: dialogue view]

what i am asking is how to put that dialogue box that made from a Rect on code under the canvas (game controller). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing that will difficult the reading of the conversation. I'd try another approach, maybe reducing the size of the dialogue box and centering it to the middle point of the screen.